# \starttextbackground is not working for me

Tags: context, texworks

I'm having trouble with `\starttextbackground`, even the examples from "Context Mark IV, an excursion" do not produce a background on a box. I'm using Context with TexWorks as a GUI wrapper, both from the Debian repo.

*Edit:*

For example …

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setuptextbackground
[frame=on, 
 framecolor=black,
 background=color,
 backgroundcolor=yellow,
 corner=round,
 location=paragraph
]

\starttext This is a \starttextbackground Test \stoptextbackground \stoptext
```

… produces:

[image]

No frame, no background

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by adding a minimal working example. `\starttext
\starttextbackground
Test
\stoptextbackground
\stoptext` works for me.

Comment: added my example & result

Comment: Your need a comma after the `paragraph` value for the `location` key.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster  Adding a comma after "paragraph" only caused a line break in the output before "Test"...

Comment: @ScottLovell If you don't want the text on a new line you need `location=text,`. Can you look for a line like this in the log file: `system > ConTeXt  ver: 2019.09.10 [...]`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster `ConTeXt  ver: 2013.06.07 17:34 MKII  fmt: 2019.10.17  int: english/english`

Comment: @ScottLovell You should really switch to MKIV

Comment: @DG' It turns out both MKII and MKIV are installed, and setting on the GUI editor I'm using as a front end were selecting the older version. It's now working as intended. [now to figure out how to mark this solved....]

Comment: One more reason to loath GUIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TexWorks setting were the problem. It was invoking MkII not MkIV. "Preferences/Typesetting/Processing tools" must be "ConTexT (LuaTex)".